# APScheduler doesnt save jobs into mongodb database

Tags: python, mongodb, flask, apscheduler

I cant save jobs into mongodb database.

I've tryed to add 'url': 'mongodb://localhost/My-db'
to default jobstore but it doesnt even compile.

```
scheduler = BackgroundScheduler({
    'apscheduler.jobstores.default': {
        'type': 'mongodb'
    },
    'apscheduler.executors.default': {
        'class': 'apscheduler.executors.pool:ThreadPoolExecutor',
        'max_workers': '20'
    },
    'apscheduler.executors.processpool': {
        'type': 'processpool',
        'max_workers': '5'
    },
    'apscheduler.job_defaults.coalesce': 'false',
    'apscheduler.job_defaults.max_instances': '3',
    'apscheduler.timezone': 'UTC',
    })
```

Comment: What doesn't compile? Are you getting an exception or what? Please post more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So actually i found by myself.Problem solved MongoClient

```
client = MongoClient('mongo_url')

jobstores = {
    'mongo': MongoDBJobStore(client=client)
}
executors = {
    'default': ThreadPoolExecutor(20),
    'processpool': ProcessPoolExecutor(5)
}
job_defaults = {
    'coalesce': False,
    'max_instances': 3
}
```